# BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$ is not closed under extension

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, lie-algebras, category-o

What is the reason for the BBG category $\mathcal{O}$ failing to be closed under extensions i.e which of the 3 axioms of $\mathcal{O}$ does not hold under taking extensions?

Is there a prototype of a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually extend two modules from $\mathcal{O}$ by a module which is not semisimple for the Cartan subalgebra (i.e. fails to be a weight module). See Exercise 3.1. in [J. E. Humphreys, Representations of semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG category $\mathcal{O}$. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 94].

Comment: Thank you very much!